# Sum of closed subgroups and linear topology

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $(G,+)$ be a $T2$ topological group endowed with a **linear topology**. It means that there is a local basis around $0$ made of subgroups.

> Pick two closed subgroups $C,D$; is it true that the sum $C+D$ is also
>   closed?

The statement is clearly false on generic topological groups, I'm just asking if the hypothesis of linear topology it is enough to make it true.

**attempt of proof:** Let $g\in (C+D)^c$ and let $U$ be a basic open subgroup contained in $C+D$, then $g+U$ is contained in $(C+D)^c$ proving that $(C+D)^c$ is open.

Comment: In the attempt of proof such $U$ not necessarily exists. For instance, there is no such $U$ when $G$ is non-discrete and $C=D=\{0\}$.

Comment: But in this case $C+D=\{0\}$ which is closed

Comment: @notsure does my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366211/example-where-a-and-b-closed-ab-not-an-f-sigma/3394295#3394295) answer your question?

Comment: @Dubious ^ ${}{}{}$